# In hyperledger fabric 2.0, Is it possible to create and deploy the chaincode in two different channels, each containing different organizations?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have been trying to create two channels, and isolate two organizations; however, when I will deploy the Chaincode in each, it is required to be endorsed by the organization contained in the other channel.

Comment: Please Provide `configtx.yaml` content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, it is possible and this is the main reason for channel in Hyperledger Fabric.

You can find that on Hyperledger Fabric's doc.

Link: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/network/network.html

You can find a tutorial on following link about how to implement that concept.

Link: https://medium.com/hackernoon/taste-all-the-features-of-hyperledger-fabric-v1-4-4275fd9b9d8e

You can also check "Profiles" in configtx.yaml file and define separate Consortiums for two channel and you can also try with 2 different chaincode name.

Profiles:

```
OrgsChannel1:
    Consortium: Consortium1
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

OrgsChannel2:
    Consortium: Consortium2
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org3
            - *Org4
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        OrdererType: etcdraft
        EtcdRaft:
            Consenters:
            - Host: orderer.example.com
              Port: 7050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
            - Host: orderer2.example.com
              Port: 8050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
            - Host: orderer3.example.com
              Port: 9050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
            - Host: orderer4.example.com
              Port: 10050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
            - Host: orderer5.example.com
              Port: 11050
              ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
        Addresses:
            - orderer.example.com:7050
            - orderer2.example.com:8050
            - orderer3.example.com:9050
            - orderer4.example.com:10050
            - orderer5.example.com:11050

        Organizations:
        - *OrdererOrg
        Capabilities:
            <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
        - <<: *OrdererOrg
    Consortiums:
        Consortium1:
            Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2

        Consortium2:
            Organizations:
            - *Org3
            - *Org4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, however, I see that these networks always have at least two organizations sharing a channel through a peer. I would like to isolate, for instance, OrG1 and Org2 in channel one, and then Org3 and Org4 on channel two. When I try to deploy the Chaincode on channel two, for example, it requires endorsement from Org1 and Org 2, but because they are part of channel one I cannot do it.

Comment: You can also check "Profiles" in configtx.yaml file and define separate Consortiums for two channel and you can also try with 2 different chaincode name like mycc1, mycc2